# Can you $unwind an array within an array when you specify the array element of the preceding array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my MongoDB aggregation I am trying to determine if I can `$unwind` an array within an array if I specifically target an element of the initial array.

This is the data structure:

```
subscription: [
  {
    agency: []
  }
]
```

What I want to do is unwind `agency` here, and since I know it will always be found within the first element of the `subscription` array, I'm doing this:

```
$unwind : {
  path: "$subscription.0.agency"
}
```

However, this doesn't work. When I plug this in as the last stage in my aggregation (which works up until this step), I end up with zero docs returned. I'm not clear why. Seems like you should be able to do this. Can you simply not `$unwind` an array within an array, even if you denote a specific array element in the path?

Comment: project it to the root level, then unwind.

Comment: Nesting unwind of array is not supported. `$unwind` also doesn't take expression and only takes string path. So you can use an extra project/addFields stage with arrayElemAt to project agency before unwinding. Something like `{$addFields:{agency:{$arrayElemAt:["$subscription", 0]}}}` Some unresolved jiras [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23754) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6436).